# untar a file with Gradle into a current directory and not create `build` directory

Tags: gradle, tar

I'm using Gradle to download a dependency that is on Nexus in tar.gz format. Next, I want to untar the content of a downloaded dependency into a current directory. Currently, I have the following Gradle script:

```
task untar(type: Copy) {
    def tarFile = file("foobar.tar.gz")
    from tarTree(tarFile)
    into buildDir
}
```

When I run the `untar` task, it creates a `build` directory and puts the content of `foobar.tar.gz` inside that directory.

Is it possible to untar the `foobar.tar.gz` into a current directory and prevent Gradle to create a `build` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saying `into System.getProperty('user.dir')` instead of `into buildDir`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't check it in the near future since I don't have access to an environment anymore.